# What will happen if the charge do not exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

It is just a naive idea, and I want some discussions to help me think deeper.

I don't know the reason of indispensability of charge, maybe some physical laws guarantee that the charge must be exist. If it is ture, could you tell me the detail about it?

My interest is what will happen if the charge do not exist in our world or universe.

Without charge, the electromagnetic field still exist, such as electromagnetic wave. But we cannot observe or measure it directly, because it will not interact with neutral matter.

But, in fact, the electromagnetic field still has some properties such that we can know it exist, for example, by gravity. The special relativity and the general relativity still correct without charge, even though the electromagnetic field will alway be a free field without electromagnetic interaction with matter. The electromagnetic field will have gravitational effect by the general relativity, but have not other effects at all.

Now, the electromagnetic field just like dark matter.

It is just a inappropriate analogy.

Maybe the dark matter or dark energy are just a free field but its charge do not exist in our universe, or its charge is too big or heavy to be created by natural process. Perhaps, someone has came up a similar idea and published.

It is just a naive idea, and I just want some discussions or comments.

Comment: I think the downvotes for this question are because it looks, at first, like you're simply asking what would happen specifically if electric charge didn't exist, when in fact you're only using that as a lead-in to your real question: could dark matter be a field without a corresponding charge? I feel like this is a more worthwhile question, so if this is what you're really trying to get at, I would recommend changing the structure of your question to emphasize that instead of electric charge specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Electric charge did not exist before the Higgs field acquired its vacuum expectation value. It was only for a very short time just after the big bang. At that time there was weak hypercharge and weak isospin. Only after the Higgs field was turned "on", these 2 charges started to mix and thus electric charge was born. Before that there was also no electromagnetic field - photons were not meaningful degrees of freedom. Just the weak hypercharge and weak isospin fields.

Such a universe would be a very different place from what we have now. The matter as we know it would not exist, particles would be different and due to the lack of Higgs field vev, lot of them would be massless (moving at the speed of light).

You can look for example [here](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-known-apparently-elementary-particles/the-known-particles-if-the-higgs-field-were-zero/) for some details.

I hope it helps answer your question, unless you imagine the loss of electric charge through a different mechanism.